# strcmp always true regardless of input

Tags: c, codeblocks

So I'm currently learning C programming in preparation for the college semester starting up. Kind of like a "leg up" thing. Anyways, I was doing some practice with comparing strings and putting new values in string arrays using the string copy function, but I'm getting some unexpected behavior that I really can't explain. It always shows a positive result for the string compare check no matter what I enter, and I can't identify where I went wrong. If someone would give me assistance I would greatly appreciate it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char tVar1[10];
    char tVar2[10];

    printf("Enter your first test variable: \n");
    scanf("%c", &tVar1);

    strcpy(tVar2, "yes");

    if(strcmp(tVar1, "yes") == 0)
        {
            printf("It would probably be more effective if you used two different variables.");
        }
    else
        {
            printf("Nope, just the same amount of effectiveness.");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` is used to read ONE character, not a line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%c` is used to read a single character value as opposed to a *string*.  When you type in your string on the terminal, only the first character is being read and assigned to `tVar1[0]`.  To read a *string* from the input stream, you need to use the `%s` conversion specifier:

```
scanf( "%9s", tVar1 ); // note no & on tVar1
```

`tVar1` is sized to hold 10 elements, which means we can read at most 9 characters into the buffer (one element must be reserved for the string terminator).  The `9` is `%9s` prevents us from reading more characters into the buffer than it can hold.

Unfortunately, the size must be hard-coded as part of the conversion specifier.  There's no way to provide the size as a run-time argument (as there is for `printf`).  There are ways around this - you can build the format string dynamically at runtime, for example - but it's a pain regardless.

Notice that we don't use a `&` for `tVar1` in the `scanf` call.  Under most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

To intake a *string*, change

```
scanf("%c", &tVar1);
```

to

```
scanf("%9s", tVar1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. Sorry to waste your time with something so simple!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read an entire input line(not just a word):

```
#define MAXLINE 9
char line[MAXLINE + 1];
fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin);
```

Note that [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf) adds a trailing newline, so you'll need to overwrite that with the null byte.

`fgets` is also better than [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf), because `scanf` leaves [stdin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/) with a newline, which will cause next input calls to be ``skipped".

Comment: Better to pass the full size as in `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);` or `fgets(line, MAXLINE + 1, stdin);`

Comment: `fgets()` does not "add" a trailing newline.  It simple saves it just like other characters should it encounter it.  `fgets()` does add a null character `'\0'` to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use %c in scanf it will read only one character. To read a word (text until white space) use %s:

```
scanf("%9s", tVar1);
```

The 9 limits the number of characters to read so that you avoid the common butter overflow vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks, that put it into perspective for me! I appreciate the answer